# How can solve the ratio

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

how can solve the problem as

$$ y(x) = \frac{1}{(a^2 + b^2)e^x + (c^2 + d^2)e^{-x}}$$

where $a, b, c$ and $d$ are constant. The answer would be in some $\operatorname{sech}$...

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 3):

To simplify that I am going to set $P= a^2+ b^2$ and $Q= c^2+ d^2$ so the equation becomes $y= \frac{1}{Pe^x+ Qe^{-x}}$.

An obvious first step is to take the reciprocal of both sides:
$\frac{1}{y}= Pe^x+ Qe^{-x}$.

Now multiply both sides by $e^x$: $\frac{1}{y}e^x= Pe^{2x}+ Q$ which is the same as $Pe^{2x}- \frac{1}{y}e^x+ Q= 0$.  Letting $z= e^x$, that is the quadratic equation $Pz^2- \frac{1}{y}z+ Q= 0$.  Use the quadratic formula to get $z= \frac{\frac{1}{y}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{y^2}- 4PQ}}{2P}$ and then solve $e^x= z$ for x.

Comment: Again not able to write the answer in terms of sech(). please further clarify your answer.